# How to add a custom Point of Interest with MapBox in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

excuse me for my bad English.
It's my first time using MapBox in Unity.
I have the doubt of how to add a point of interest in a specific sector, as it would be a house or a local in particular.
Also, I would like you to show me a message by approaching this point.
I've been looking for documentation on the subject, but I do not find anything useful.
Thank you so much for everything.

Comment: Have you looked at the [point of interest (POI) demo](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/examples/poi-placement/)? What things have you tried with Mapbox? Have you looked at Studio to create datasets that you can use in Unity with the Mapbox plugin? I know the Mapbox documentation is a bit superficial, and you will need to dig into the code to figure out what is going on. If you can be more specific about what things you have and have not tried we will be able to give you a better answer.

Comment: Excuse my ambiguous explanation.
What I need is to be able to place a specific point. In the demo, they show predetermined places, or at least that's what I understand in the documentation.
An example of what I need, could be: in an area with 6 houses aligned, I need to mark only the first and the last.
I hope to have explained myself better.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Spend some time exploring Mapbox Studio and getting a good understanding of datasets and tilesets and how they are created and relate to each other. That will make the following much easier to understand. To add new POIs from user input in Unity, here is a basic outline of what you'll need to do:

1. Create a dataset in Mapbox (and, optionally, see below, a tileset)
2. In Unity, perform a hit test to determine where the user has clicked. Use the AbstractMap GameObject to translate Unity coordinates to geographical coordinates.
3. Use a Mapbox API to upload the data:
   a. Uploads API - multi-step process, but produces a tileset: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/upload-curl/
   b. Dataset API - will require you to read from the dataset later: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#insert-or-update-a-feature

If you used 3.a, you should be able to use the POI demo directly, since it gets its data from a tileset. See the explanation of the [Data Explorer sample](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/examples/data-explorer/). Map Id is the id of your tileset.

If you use 3.b, you will need to write your own code to query the dataset API directly and use the provided methods to transform the geographical coordinate to Unity world space.

If you don't need to update your dataset in real time, you could update the dataset, then go into Mapbox Studio and manually update the tileset, at which point the new data would be available next time you run your Unity project. It all depends on your specific requirements.